# Autofixture: Using AutoMoqCustomization & SetupAllProperties to have all properties of a mocked interface fillled?

Tags: moq, autofixture, automoq

I am trying to get Autofixture to setup and create me an anonymous of an interface. I am using the AutoMoqCustomization, but I keep getting an error.

My code is

```
var configuration = fixture.CreateAnonymous<Mock<IConfiguration>>();

Mock.Get(configuration).SetupAllProperties();
```

It actually errors on the `SetupAllProperties` with

> System.ArgumentException : Object instance was not created by Moq.
>   Parameter name: mocked

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to get a `Mock<IConfiguration>` from a `Mock<IConfiguration>` instance, which is hardly necessary. Just use

```
var configuration = fixture.CreateAnonymous<Mock<IConfiguration>>();

configuration.SetupAllProperties();
```